# zend soap error xml declaration

Tags: zend-framework, soap

It looked easy, but it is consuming my hours in a terribly way!

Based on: http://www.opensourceuniverse.com/zend-framework/quickstart-web-services-with-soap-and-zend-framework-263.html , no changes made, i get:

url:
(...)/public/soap?wsdl

Here the apache error log:
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost/test/app/public/soap?wsdl' : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document\n in C:\wamp\www\test\app\library\Zend\Soap\Server.php on line 762

And if url:
(...)/public/soap/client

result:
Page stays blank (there exists a view for clientAction, tested.)
Here I have checked that it gets the view when I comment the call to the client method, i mean:

$client = new Zend_Soap_Client($this->_WSDL_URI);

//  $this->view->add_result = $client->math_add(11, 55);

some nice clues around?
Pablo

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

It was because i use a layout.

To be sure to dont (pre|ap)end things to your XML file use :

```
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
```

Comment: yes, right. Are you working already with zend_soap? i'll post another question btw.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, just in case, i expose: was a whitespace in application.ini, in between lines!